# How to handle aggregation with ElastiSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

The query:

```
GET test5/_search
{
   "size": 1,
   "aggregations": {
      "Location": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "Location"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The Output:

```
   {
           "took": 5,
           "timed_out": false,
           "_shards": {
              "total": 5,
              "successful": 5,
              "failed": 0
           },
           "hits": {
              "total": 19,
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                 {
                    "_index": "test5",
                    "_type": "xxxxxx",
                    "_id": "AVLOBXbvFe2VQdUY7tZu",
                    "_score": 1,
                    "_source": {
                        fired",
                       "Host": "N/A",

                       "Mac": "N/A",
                       "Destination IP": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                       "Location": "United States",
                       "Events/Flows": "107",
                       "Asset Name": "N/A",
                       "Custom Rule XXXX :": "xxxxxxfp",
                       "User": "N/A"
                    }
                 }
              ]
           },
           "aggregations": {
              "Location": {
                 "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                 "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                 "buckets": [
                    {
                       "key": "other",
                       "doc_count": 11
                    },
                    {
                       "key": "states",
                       "doc_count": 2
                    },
                    {
                       "key": "united",
                       "doc_count": 2
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
```

You can noticed that United States has been taken as two keys. How to get united states as sigle key?

Comment: in the mapping change `Location` field to be [not_analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/string.html#string) and reindex

Comment: can you please give me the syntax? I coudn't get this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your `Location` field is `not_analyzed` otherwise its value will be tokenized and analyzed by ES, so that `United States` becomes the two tokens you see: `united` and `states`

When [creating your mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html), you need to make sure you  have your `Location` field looking like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test5/_mapping/xxxxxx -d '{
  "properties": {
    ... your other fields...
    "Location": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"           <--- make sure to add this
    }
  }
}
```